# redirect stdin and stdout using tee and keep previous std

Tags: bash, shell

How can I both write to a file and display to screen using pipe with `tee`?

This command actually do it, the problem is that it writes to a new file and `tail -f` give me an error "truncate file".

```
ls -al | tee file.txt
```

Comment: So you want to use `tee`, but append rather than truncate the file?

Comment: yeah that's what I want to do

Comment: Take a look at the [manpage for `tee`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) and see if there's anything that applies to your problem there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-a` option of tee is what you are looking for

```
 -a, --append
              append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
```

so your line would be:

```
ls -al | tee -a file.txt
```